# Install TWRP in Essential Phone(PH-1): No such partition

Tags: root-access, twrp

I have unlocked bootloader, and in bootloader, I follow the instructions on [TWRP site](https://twrp.me/essential/essentialph1.html):

[image]

But I failed with `No such partition`.

Here is my log:

```
➜  platform-tools ./adb shell getprop ro.boot.slot_suffix
_b
➜  platform-tools ./fastboot flash boot ~/Downloads/twrp-3.2.3-0-mata.img
Sending 'boot__b' (48712 KB)                       OKAY [  2.086s]
Writing 'boot__b'                                  FAILED (remote: 'No such partition.')
fastboot: error: Command failed
➜  platform-tools ./fastboot --set-active=_a
Slot _a does not exist. supported slots are:
a
b
➜  platform-tools ./fastboot --set-active=a
Setting current slot to 'a'                        OKAY [  0.162s]
Finished. Total time: 0.162s
➜  platform-tools ./fastboot flash boot ~/Downloads/twrp-3.2.3-0-mata.img
Sending 'boot__a' (48712 KB)                       OKAY [  1.145s]
Writing 'boot__a'                                  FAILED (remote: 'No such partition.')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Could anyone please give me some hints about that problem?

Comment: *fastboot flash boot_a ~/Downloads/twrp-3.2.3-0-mata.img*

Answer (score 0):

If you're flashing to partition `a`, use `boot_a`. This worked for me on my Essential PH-1.

```
fastboot flash:raw boot_a
```